# Вывод информации между страницами javascript

Tags: javascript, html

При нажатии кнопки на первой странице нужно вывести информацию в тег (P) на вторую страницу хотел сделать это через innerHTML но код срабатывает только если присваивать его в одиночную страницу где находится кнопка подскажите что можно добавить или убрать

**Первая страница**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Round One</p>
    <h1>вопрос?</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="optradio"checked>ответ
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="optradio">ответ
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="optradio">ответ
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" id="radio4" name="optradio">ответ
          </label>
        </form>
      </div>


            <a href="level2.html" class="myButton" onclick="func4()">Next</a>


        <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Вторая страница на которую нужно вывести информацию**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Congratulations</p>
    <h1 id="">Your score is:</h1>
    <p id="output">score</p>


       <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="">Next Round</a>


    <script src="script.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

**JS код**

```
    function func4() {


    var p;
    p = document.getElementById('output');
    p.innerHTML = "hello"

   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
localStorage["key"] = value;
```

... на другой странице ...

```
value = localStorage["key"];
```

Comment: это можно в одной функции реализовать или разделить их?

Comment: Та без разницы. LocalStorage один. На Ваше усмотрение

Comment: На одной странице сохраняете параметр в localStorage в одной js функции. На другой странице в другой функции достаете этот параметр